# java/android datetime timespan

Tags: java, android, clock

If i have a simpledateformat object:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

And have two times, 12:12 and 13:13 for example, is there an easy way to check if the current time is between the two SimpleDateFormats (The clock is 12:15 for example)? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");    

Date d1 = newDateFormat.parse("12:12");
Date d2 = newDateFormat.parse("13:13");
Date myDate = newDateFormat.parse("12:15");

if(myDate.getTime() >= d1.getTime() && myDate.getTime() <= d2.getTime()){
//yes it is in between  including border
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare them using `Date` or `Calendar` objects, `SimpleDateFormat` is just a representation. You can use `format.parse("12:12")` and ir returns a `Date` object representing that time.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a better and lighter library to use in Android/ Java that handles interval better, you can use a library that a wrote to use in my own Android app. https://github.com/ashokgelal/samaya

Also, see this question: [Do we have a TimeSpan sort of class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581605/do-we-have-a-timespan-sort-of-class-in-java/7017916#7017916)