# Handling Date(add,sub) in Liferay

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, alloy-ui

**How to subtract date(using calendar) entered using jsp page with current date ? i am using liferay 6.1.**

*sorry i am new to stack overflow.*

**Actually my requirement is**:

I have to achieve inter-portlet-communication using events,where p-1-publisher portlet,p-2-listener portlet.
 I have 3 fields in p-1 name, address and date of birth after submitting p-2 should show:- "HELLO username x-y-z days LEFT FOR YOUR BIRTHDAY".

**My Error Code Is Bellow:**

**For portlet p-1** : *jsp page*

```
  <portlet:defineObjects />

<portlet:actionURL var="publishEventUrl" name="publishEvent">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="publishEventUrl"/>
 </portlet:actionURL>
<aui:form name="usrfm" action="${publishEventUrl}" method="post">
     <aui:input name="userName" label="Enter User Name:" />
     <aui:input name="userAddress" label="Enter User Address:" />
     <aui:input name="userDob"  type="date" />
     <aui:button type="submit" value="submit"/>
</aui:form>
```

*controller class*

```
public class EventGenerator extends MVCPortlet {

Log _log=LogFactoryUtil.getLog(EventGenerator.class);

@ProcessAction(name="publishEventUrl")
public void publishEvent(ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

    _log.info("inside event generator start");
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    /*
     * get sample text from UI
    */
    String Name=ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "userName");
    String Address=ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "userAddress");
    //String date=ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "userDOB");
    Date date=ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest, "startDateHidden", dateFormat);
    //String startDateString=ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"startDateHidden");

    User user=new User();

    user.setUserName(Name);
    user.setUserAddress(Address);
    user.setUserDob(date);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.add(Calendar.DATE, -(long)date);

    QName qname= new QName("http://liferay.com", "user", "x");
    actionResponse.setEvent( qname, user);
    _log.info("user>>>>>>>>>>>" +user);

    _log.info("inside event generator end");
}
```

}

**For portlet p-2**
*EventReceiver controller class*

```
 public class EventReceiver extends MVCPortlet {
Log _log=LogFactoryUtil.getLog(EventReceiver.class);

@ProcessEvent(qname="{http://liferay.com}user")
public void getEvent(EventRequest request, EventResponse response)
        throws PortletException, IOException {

    _log.info("inside user_receiver Start");

    Event event=request.getEvent();
    User user=(User) event.getValue();
    System.out.println("user>>>>>>>" +user);
    request.setAttribute("user", user);


    _log.info("inside user_receiver end");
}
```

}

**jsp page**

```
 <portlet:defineObjects />
<%
     User user=(User)request.getAttribute("user"); 

%>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>UserAddress</th>
            <th>D.O.B</th>
      </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>${user.userName}</td>
               <td>${user.userAddress}</td>
               <td>${user.userDob}</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code of any attempts, even if wrong, you may have made so far?

Comment: Additionally, it's very unclear what you mean. Examples of what you're trying to achieve (user input, expected output) would help.

Comment: This is totally unrelated to Liferay - it's just plain date algorithm and you'll find loads of examples. I can't point you to one because I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve: Add days? Time difference?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The code you posted really hid the description that you edited into the question well. The code doesn't do what you ask (e.g. calculate the difference to the birthday) and is really complicated - I don't understand what the inter portlet communication does here.

For the difference between two dates, I'll point to another question already asked here, utilizing Joda Time: [How to calculate the difference between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893). I'll leave the exercise of finding out if this year's birthday is already in the past or still in the future to you.

Now, as you post quite a lot of code, here's my initial answer from when I totally missed the actual (edited) question in the beginning:

When I look at your code, the relevant parts seem to be starting here

```
<aui:form name="usrfm" action="${publishEventUrl}" method="post">
     <aui:input name="userName" label="Enter User Name:" />
     <aui:input name="userAddress" label="Enter User Address:" />
     <aui:input name="userDob"  type="date" />
     <aui:button type="submit" value="submit"/>
</aui:form>
```

Note that there's no parameter named `startDateHidden` that you seem to read in your action handler:

```
Date date=ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest, "startDateHidden", dateFormat);
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.add(Calendar.DATE, -(long)date);
```

So, where ever you get your start date from, it seems like you want to subtract one date from another - what's the expected outcome? What's the result of "19. Januar 2015 *minus* 12. December 2014"? This won't work. You might want to subtract durations from dates, but not dates from each other. [Check JodaTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581605) to make your time/date handling easier.