# C# Timespan equivalent in java?

Tags: java, timespan

I am trying to convert the following code which is in c# to java. And I am facing difficulty in converting it. Please can anyone suggest me a simple way to do it in Java.

```
 DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(PWUpdatedOn.Year, 01, 01);
 TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(PWUpdatedOn.Ticks - StartDate.Ticks);
 //Response.Write(ts.Days+1); 
 days = ts.Days + 1;
 lngN = 0;

 PWUpdatedOn.Year = 2016 // current year
```

Comment: Depends on which Java version you're looking to make it work. In Java 8 there are the `java.time.*` classes that can do that for you, but before that you'll either have to use the JodaTime library or do the math on your own using primitive values.

Comment: Check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html for java 8

Answer (score 2):

As [Jigar Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260990/jigar-joshi) answered in an other [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581621/2972104).

> [Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Interval.html) from JodaTime will do..
>
> > A time interval represents a period of time between two instants. Intervals >are inclusive of the start instant and exclusive of the end. The end instant is always greater than or equal to the start instant.
> >     Intervals have a fixed millisecond duration. This is the difference between the start and end instants. 
> >     The duration is represented separately by ReadableDuration. As a result, intervals are not comparable. To compare the length of two intervals, you should compare their durations.
> >
> > An interval can also be converted to a ReadablePeriod. This represents the difference between the start and end points in terms of fields such as years and days.
> >
> > Interval is thread-safe and immutable.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what Ticks are in C#. But it would be something like:

```
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.of(PWUpdatedOn.getYear(), 1, 1);
    Period ts = Period.between(PWUpdatedOn, startDate.toLocalDate());
    days = ts.getDays() + 1;
```

Note that Period.between() requires two LocalDate instances. If PWUpdateOn is a LocalDateTime instance, it needs to be converted with the method toLocalDate().

Some potentially relevant remarks: for zoned datetimes, use ZonedDateTime rather than LocalDateTimel; all time and period objects are immutable in Java.