# How to convert "2017-07-12T18:43:04.000Z" to relative time in android or java?

Tags: java, android, datetime

How to convert "2017-07-12T18:43:04.000Z" to ago format like 1 hour ago or 1 week ago?

Comment: please follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581605/do-we-have-a-timespan-sort-of-class-in-java

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: have you searched google?

Comment: yeah..couldn't figure anything out.

Comment: Step 1: Parse timestamp.  Step 2: Compare timestamp with current time.  Step 3: Declare victory.

Comment: You should work with this guy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120995/how-to-format-time-with-to-timeago-in-android

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a zero-effort requirements dump.

Answer (score 0):

You must convert your `dtStart` string to date object by `SimpleDateFormat`.
After that you can get it in millisecond with `date.getTime()` method and calculate it's difference to current time. Now from this difference you can get the ago format you want:

```
public String getDate(String dtStart) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(dtStart);

        long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - date.getTime();
        long hours = Math.round(diff / (60 * 60 * 1000));


        if(hours < 24) {
            return hours + " hours ago";
        } else {
            long days = Math.round(diff / (24.0 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

            if (days == 0)
                return "today";
            else if (days == 1)
                return "yesterday";
            else if (days < 14)
                return days + " days ago";
            else if (days < 30)
                return ((int) (days / 7)) + " weeks ago";
            else if (days < 365)
                return ((int) (days / 30)) + " months ago";
            else
                return ((int) (days / 365)) + " years ago";
        }


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.