# How to calculate Time ago in in java(jsp)

Tags: java, jsp, web-deployment

friends
im new using date and time in java.
I stored date and time in String which is the current time similarly I have one more string variable which has the post time
now I want to calculate the ago time even in seconds on any
the string has date and time in this format yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
can some one help me
Thank you
here is the code

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

        LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.parse(d_tt, formatter);
        LocalDateTime postTime = LocalDateTime.parse(post_time, formatter);

        long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(postTime, currentTime);//(error here)
```

error "ChronoUnit cannot be
resolved"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do we have a TimeSpan sort of class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581605/do-we-have-a-timespan-sort-of-class-in-java)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate time difference in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case it is best to use [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

First you have to convert the two strings into a LocalDateTime

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.parse(currentTimeString, formatter); // Or use LocalDateTime.now()
LocalDateTime postTime = LocalDateTime.parse(postTimeString, formatter);
```

These objects can then be used to determine the time between them. There are two possibilities to do this. All of them give the same result, which you can use to determine the time between them according to your own preferences.

**Possibility 1:**

```
long seconds = postTime.until(currentTime, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Possibility 1:**

```
long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(postTime, currentTime);
```

You can also get more information here:

1. [Introduction to the Java 8 Date/Time API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro)
2. [Java 8: Difference between two LocalDateTime in multiple units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-difference-between-two-localdatetime-in-multiple-units)

Comment: I tried this but im getting an error at ChronoUnit "ChronoUnit cannot be resolved to a variable" i did import java.time and I'm using java 11

Comment: @Education4Fun Could you please attach your code to the question, so it is easier to answer your question

Comment: long seconds = postTime.until(currentTime, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
or long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(postTime, currentTime);
 same error

Comment: Are you _importing_ `ChronoUnit`?  `import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;`.

Comment: errors are resolved but the output is 0. will try to resolve them thanks for the help.